# Bootstrap Breadcrumb going into center dive when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, breadcrumbs

I set up a site map page and am using breadcrumbs at the top to take the user to the direct spot their looking for sense it got a little long. However when they click the bread crumb in goes to the correct div, but in goes to far down.

Here is my code

```
<div class="container" style="border: 1px solid black;">
    <div class="row" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #3a5d85; ">
            <h3 style="text-align: center; font-size: 40px;"><b>Site Map</b></h3>

        <ul class="breadcrumb" style="font-size: 18px;">
            <li class="actve"><a href="#Company">Company</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#Resources">Resources</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#Signs">Signs</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#Magnets">Magnets</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#Banners">Banners</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#Stickers">Stickers & Decals</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#Yard">Yard Signs</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#Business">Business Signs</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#Social">Social</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="Company">
        <ul>
            <!--Company-->
                <h3>Company</h3>

            <li>About</li>
            <li>Services</li>
            <li>Contact Us</li>
        </ul>
        <!--End Company-->
    </div>
    <div id="Resources">
        <ul id="Resources">
            <!--Resources-->
                <h3>Resources</h3>

            <li>FAQ</li>
            <li>Terms of Sale</li>
            <li>Terms of Service</li>
            <li>Privacy Policy</li>
        </ul>
        <!--End Resources-->
    </div>
    <div id="Signs">
        <ul id="Signs">
            <!--Signs-->
                <h3>Signs</h3>

            <li>Real Estate</li>
            <li>Art Prints</li>
            <li>Street Signs</li>
            <li>Political Signs</li>
            <li>Property Signs</li>
            <li>For Sale Signs</li>
            <li>Safety Signs</li>
            <li>Traffic Signs</li>
            <li>Novelty License Plates</li>
            <li>Oversized Checks</li>
        </ul>
        <!--End Signs-->
    </div>
    <div id="Magnets">
        <ul id="Magnets">
            <!--Magnets-->
                <h3>Magnets</h3>

            <li>General Magnets</li>
            <ul>
                <li>Events</li>
                <li>Restaurants</li>
                <li>Business</li>
                <li>Services</li>
                <li>Political</li>
                <li>General</li>
            </ul>
            <li>Car Magnets</li>
            <ul>
                <li>Events</li>
                <li>Restaurants</li>
                <li>Business</li>
                <li>Services</li>
                <li>Political</li>
                <li>General</li>
            </ul>
            <li>Fridge Magnets</li>
            <ul>
                <li>Promotional</li>
                <li>Calendar</li>
                <li>Reminder</li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
        <!--End Magnets-->
    </div>
    <div id="Banners">
        <ul id="Banners">
            <!--Banners-->
                <h3>Banners</h3>

            <li>Custom Vinyl Banners</li>
            <ul>
                <li>Events</li>
                <li>Birthdays</li>
                <li>Sports</li>
                <li>Schools</li>
                <li>Organizations</li>
                <li>Real Estate</li>
                <li>Religous</li>
                <li>Holidays</li>
                <li>Political</li>
            </ul>
            <li>General Banners</li>
            <ul>
                <li>Events</li>
                <li>Birthdays</li>
                <li>Sports</li>
                <li>Schools</li>
                <li>Organizations</li>
                <li>Real Estate</li>
                <li>Religous</li>
                <li>Holidays</li>
                <li>Political</li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
        <!--End Banners-->
    </div>
    <div id="Stickers">
        <ul id="Stickers">
            <!--Stickers & Decals-->
                <h3>Stickers & Decals</h3>

            <li>Digital Print Decals</li>
            <ul>
                <li>School</li>
                <li>Car Clubs</li>
                <li>Sports</li>
                <li>Political</li>
                <li>"I Heart" Pictures</li>
                <li>Religous</li>
            </ul>
            <li>Vinyl lettering</li>
            <ul>
                <li>School</li>
                <li>Car Clubs</li>
                <li>Sports</li>
                <li>Political</li>
                <li>"I Heart" Pictures</li>
                <li>Religous</li>
            </ul>
            <li>Window Decals</li>
            <ul>
                <li>School</li>
                <li>Car Clubs</li>
                <li>Sports</li>
                <li>Political</li>
                <li>"I Heart" Pictures</li>
                <li>Religous</li>
            </ul>
            <li>Bumper Stickers</li>
            <ul>
                <li>School</li>
                <li>Car Clubs</li>
                <li>Sports</li>
                <li>Political</li>
                <li>"I Heart" Pictures</li>
                <li>Religous</li>
            </ul>
            <li>Store Front Decals</li>
            <ul>
                <li>Store Hours</li>
                <li>Legal Info</li>
                <li>Social Media Decals</li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
        <!--End Stickers & Decals-->
    </div>
    <div id="Yard">
        <ul id="Yard">
            <!--Yard Signs-->
                <h3>Yard Signs</h3>

            <li>Now Open</li>
            <li>Political</li>
            <li>For Sale</li>
            <li>Business</li>
            <li>Promotional</li>
            <li>Events</li>
            <li>Parking</li>
        </ul>
        <!--End yard Signs-->
    </div>
    <div id="Business">
        <ul id="Business">
            <!--Business Signs-->
                <h3>Business Signs</h3>

            <li>Business Signs</li>
        </ul>
        <!--End Business Signs-->
    </div>
    <div id="Social">
        <ul id="Social">
            <!--Social-->
                <h3>Social Media</h3>

            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Twitter</li>
            <li>Instagram</li>
        </ul>
        <!--End Social-->
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I can get it to work in JSfiddle using the exact same code [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/nojil/yrmwpg79/1/)

Here it is on the website im working on, [Working website](http://gotospectrum.com/SiteMap.html)

As you can see on my working webpage it will go past the header a few lines?

Comment: looks like you're not accounting for the offset introduced by the top-level nav.

Comment: Charles, please try my answer and let me know your comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have a fixed header, you need `padding` to the element of the height of the header and a negative `margin` of the same height to the element to offset the fixed header height. Create a class called `.fake-margin` to the elements with `id` links used for `href="#{idlink}"` and give the following CSS:

```
.fake-margin {
  margin-top: -72px; /* Header height + margin */
  padding-top: 72px; /* Header height + margin */
}
```

Now add this class `fake-margin` to those links, namely:

```
<div id="Company" class="fake-margin">
<div id="Resources" class="fake-margin">
<div id="Signs" class="fake-margin">
<div id="Magnets" class="fake-margin">
<div id="Banners" class="fake-margin">
```

And so on. It doesn't show in your fiddle because, the fiddle does not have a fixed header in place. `:)`

Comment: Awesome! thank you so much, that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: i have to wait 4 minutes